# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError during migrations

Tags: django, validation

I can't migrate, because Django gives me the following error:

> `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [u"'NULL' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]`

This is my code:

```
update_time = models.DateTimeField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.update_time = timezone.now()
    return super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_update_time(self):
    return self.clean_update_time_date
```

I don't know what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing `DateTimeField` in your database has some `NULL` values, but your current model defintion does not allow `NULL` values in the database. So either change `update_time` to allow `NULL` values or delete these entries from the database.

```
update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```